# Why the last list in the slider not fadeIn/FadeOut/show/hide?

Tags: jquery, css, list, slider, fadein

I have an easyslider with divs within lists to show content, such that when I hover over one list, the hidden div   is displayed via fadeIn Fadeout Jquery.

It works fine for all the list except the last list.Where in the Hidden Content just does not show up.
Can some one please help ?

One think I have noticed is that when i insert a blank list after the last list, it seems to work.
Is that the only work-around this?

Link to DropBox:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7940498/testtes/bb/01Test_X.html

Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/newbie_ready_to_learn/kQnFj/1/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Cont_All1").hover(function(){
        $("#HiddenCont1").fadeIn(700);
},function(){
        $("#HiddenCont1").fadeOut(900);
});

 $("#Cont_All2").hover(function(){
        $("#HiddenCont2").fadeIn(700);
},function(){
        $("#HiddenCont2").fadeOut(900);
});

 $("#Cont_All3").hover(function(){
        $("#HiddenCont3").fadeIn(700);
},function(){
        $("#HiddenCont3").fadeOut(900);
});

 $("#Cont_All4").hover(function(){
        $("#HiddenCont4").fadeIn(700);
},function(){
        $("#HiddenCont4").fadeOut(900);
});
});

</script>


<div>
<li>
<div #Cont_All1>
      <div Img>
      </div>
     Content
      <div #HiddenCont1>
     </div>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<div #Cont_All2>
      <div Img>
      </div>
     Content
      <div #HiddenCont2>
     </div>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<div #Cont_All3>
      <div Img>
      </div>
     Content
      <div #HiddenCont3>
     </div>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<div #Cont_All4>
      <div Img>
      </div>
     Content
      <div #HiddenCont4>
     </div>
</div>
</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ or equivalent. People will be reluctant to download your code pages.

Comment: seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YY4Ue/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/newbie_ready_to_learn/kQnFj/1/   here is the jsfiddle file. i hope the border styles make sense.

Comment: Did you mean the first?

Comment: yes, i dont know how the fourth is kept at the top in jsfiddle..if you open the drop box link,  its the fourth one in which the hover - does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to remove the first block that goes from `<li><div id="Cont_All1">` on line 5 to `</div></div></li>` on line 25 and the problem didn't happen.

So there's no problem in jQuery code, but probably you forgot to close some tag or make some `id` mistake in your HTML code. So... I've tried to remove the first block, copy the second block and rename it with `Cont_All1` and `HiddenCont1` instead of `Cont_All2` and `HiddenCont2` and the job is done, easily as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fECnT/1/).

Comment: I copied your html and kept everything exactly the same.But it does not work. Your jsfiddle file seems to be working I am starting to wonder if this is caused due to the slider i am using -easySlider. did you have a look at the dropbox link I shared.

Comment: I have to go now, I'm sorry. I don't know that lib, try to check config parameters.